# Object has no method Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I don't know why I am getting this problem. I have used prototype before in javascript and it works fine but for some reason it is not working here:

test.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        UserOptions("test");
    });
</script>
```

UserOptions.js:

```
 function UserOptions(username){
    ...
    var userOptions = document.createElement("div");
    userOptions.className = "userOptions";
    **this.createBtns(userOptions);**
    userContainer.appendChild(userOptions);


    contentCenter.appendChild(userContainer);
    contentCenter.appendChild(br);

    BuddyList();
    }

    UserOptions.prototype = {
        createBtns:function(parent){
            var self = this;
            /* Add Buddy Button */
            var addBtnContainer = document.createElement("div");
            addBtnContinaer.className = "addBtnContainer";
    ...}
```

I keep getting the error Object has no method 'createBtns'

Comment: Could you also post the line where you try to create the object?

Comment: Where and when do you get this error?

Comment: I get the error on the line : this.createBtns(userOptions); I bolded it

Comment: @Twidizle: Yes, I can see that line, but I want the line where you try to create an instance of UserOptions.

Comment: You realize that the last line of "creteBtns" has a misspelling, right?

Comment: yeah but createBtns doesn't even execute... so that's not the problem

Answer (score 11):

You forgot the `new` keyword. Now it's trying to call your constructor as a regular function, and this will point to `window` or whatever.

```
new UserOptions("Fred");
```

Comment: ty... I forgot that prototype makes javacript "object oriented"

Comment: @Twidizle: You might want to start marking good answers on your questions as accepted (green tick mark next to the score). I see you haven't marked any accepted answers on your previous ones.

Comment: @Twidizle `new` is not a prototype thing. It's a Javascript thing.

Comment: More accurately, prototype makes javascript more class oriented -- javascript is objected oriented already.