# Object has no method "charAt"

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following function to get the elevation on Google Maps:

```
function getElevation(event) {
    var locations = [];
    var clickedLocation = event.latLng;
    locations.push(clickedLocation);

    var positionalRequest = {
        'locations': locations
    }

    elevator.getElevationForLocations(positionalRequest, function(results, status) {
        if(status == google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK) {
            var s = results[0].elevation;

            if(results[0]) {
                $('#elevation').html(parseInt(s).charAt(0) + ' meter');
            } else {
                alert('Inget resultat hittades');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Det gick inte att hitta höjdskillnaden på grund av följande: ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object 65 has no method 'charAt'` when I click somewhere on the map and I don't know how I shall fix this problem. `parseInt(s)` prints for example 44 depending on where you click on the map. If I click on the ocean it shows for example -4837 and it's just that minus character I want to identify if it's exists in this string.

Any ideas of how I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object has no method Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905028/object-has-no-method-javascript) Please stop asking the same question over and over again with changes to the missing method name - the **same exact reason** applies to them all, and the logic to solve them all is **exactly** the same in every case. If you insist on duplicating the question over and over and over again, I'll have no choice but to start flagging them for moderator attention. If you actually **read** the answers to the posts that you're duplicating, you can figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers don't have a "charAt()" method on their prototype, but strings do.

```
$('#elevation').html(('' + parseInt(s)).charAt(0) + ' meter');
```

The `parseInt()` function returns a number. You have to explicitly convert it to a string first.

Why it is that you're trying to make it a number in the first place is a little mysterious.

Comment: (Specifying a radix will stave off the insidious Octaliens!)

Comment: @pst yes that's true, but in this particular case it seems likely that the best thing to do is not call `parseInt()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
parseInt(s).charAt(0)
```

You are parsing a string and returning an integer, and then trying to call charAt on an integer, which won't work too well. You should call charAt before you parse it.